# Rails console/pry shows ActiveRecord has_many/belongs_to references in invalid state?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, pry

I have a fairly simple has_many/belongs_to relationship in two models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :authorizations, dependent: :destroy
  ...
end

class Authorization < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  ...
end
```

...all good.

But when I have users with existing authorizations, and use rails console ***(note that I'm actually using the pry gem -- could this be pry-related?)*** to reassign some of those authorizations to a different user, like this:

```
> some_auth = user_b.authorizations.first
> user_a << some_auth
> some_auth.user = user_a
> some_auth.save
```

...then I get weird conflicting states of ownership:

```
> user_b.authorizations.count
=> 0

> user_b.authorizations.first
=> #<Authorization id: 7, user_id: 9, ...>

> user_b.authorizations.first.user_id
=> 9

> user_a.authorizations.first.user
=> #<User id: 7, ...>
```

Totally weird, right?

Now, I'm guessing I don't need to do both

```
> user_a << some_auth
```

and

```
> some_auth.user = user_a
```

...but I wouldn't expect this behavior just from that redundancy!

Can someone help me figure out what's going wrong?

Note that when I quit the rails console and start it again, the problem seems to go away...

Comment: I think you're bumping into association caching. The behavior described looks normal to me.

Answer (score 2):

To solve your case you may want to use `:inverse_of` option with your `Authorization` class. It will look like `belongs_to :user, inverse_of: :authorizations` - and then it will work like you expect it to.

You can read more at "Setting Inverses" section of [the docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html).

Comment: Thanks! The docs suggest that automatic inverse detection should be working in a case as simple, and named in a standard mannar, as this one.